# QT 5.0.1 crashes when compiling in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: qt5

I've got some problems compiling a basic Qt application in Visual Studio 2012 together with the the Qt Add-in.
I just compiled Qt 5.0.1 x64 myself as described on the Qt website and on this board, then I downloaded the Qt Visual Studio Add-in and installed it.
In VS I opened a new Qt application and tried to compile it, but it says something like "fatal error lnk1104 qt5cored5.lib cannot be opened"
So I looked into the lib folder and could only find a qt5cored.lib. So I copied it and renamed it as qt5cored5.lib. After a next try to compile my project VS says:
"LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "Qt5Widgetsd5.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden."
What means that VS could find the qt5cored5.lib now but not the qt5widgets5.lib.

Any ideas why I haven't got the right libraries in my lib folder or why VS asks for libraries I don't have?
Is there anything I could have made wrong, when compiling Qt?

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go through the Qt compilation process again from scratch, to see if you missed a step or something. Maybe first read through the steps if you can spot the problem, then clean and redo.

If you have resorted to manually copying libs, then very likely you forgot something, such as actually installing the compiled Qt libs...

Here's [a link to one forum discussion about subject](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13629), and here's [a link to wiki guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) for building Qt5.